# How to assign value to dictionary saved as Any in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a **value wrapper**, which stores value in `Any` type. When stored value is a dictionary, I don't know how to update the value of `dictionary` of specific key. Assignment to casted value causes compile error.

Example:

```
var learning: Any = [ "name": "C++" ]
(learning as! [String: String])["name"] = "Swift"
```

Compiler complains "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String?'"

Comment: I think you need to go via a temp variable, cast to temp -> update temp -> assign temp to original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the type cast is immutable, you have to assign the result to a variable

```
var learning: Any = [ "name": "C++" ]
var dictionary = learning as! [String: String]
dictionary["name"] = "Swift"
```

By the way `Any` is the worst choice